# Objective C static class member having bad access

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, static-members

I am trying to use the static variable here tagsToCheck, accessible from all static methods in this class. 
What is the best way?

A retain here solve the problem, but is it the right way?

```
tagsToCheck = [@[@"<html>", @"<br>", @"<br />", @"<br/>", @"<p>", @"<div>", @"<b>",
                              @"<i>", @"<font>", @"<ul>", @"<li>"] retain];
```

The original code is,

```
static NSArray * tagsToCheck = nil;

@implementation DictionaryUtil

+ (void) initialize {
    tagsToCheck = @[@"<html>", @"<br>", @"<br />", @"<br/>", @"<p>", @"<div>", @"<b>",
                              @"<i>", @"<font>", @"<ul>", @"<li>"];
}

+ (BOOL) isHtml:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!string) return NO;

    for (NSString *tag in tagsToCheck) { // bad access here for tagsToCheck
        if ([string rangeOfString:tag options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: R you calling **initialize** method before to use of **tagsToCheck** ??

Comment: for static methods, I guess, +(void) initialize () {} is called by default, before any other static methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Objective-C array literal is an `autorelease`d object, so using `retain` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using retain is *not* the best way. The best way is to **enable Automatic Reference Counting**.

Comment: I could not use ARC, since the app supports old iOS 4.3

Comment: @karim iOS 4 **supports** ARC, but not _weak_ references.